How to show all current ssh connected users on Linux?
Using GCP VM Instance, I'm connected via ssh, not serial port. When I type w or who or finger I get the following output:
$ w
08:46:18 up 41 min,  0 users,  load average: 0.10, 0.07, 0.01
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT

$ who                                                                                                                         

$ finger                                                                                                                      No one logged on.

I'm expecting to see my current connected user, but this is not the case. I tried to connect as another user along mine and it showed, but not my primary user, either when he or the other runs the command.
> pstree -alus "$$" 
systemd
  └─sshd
      └─sshd
          └─sshd,Dédé
              └─bash
                  └─bash
                      └─code-e170252f76 command-shell --cli-data-dir /home/Dédé/.vscode-server/cli --parent-process-id 234934 --on-port
                          └─sh /home/Dédé/.vscode-server/cli/servers/Stable-e170252f762678dec6ca2cc69aba1570769a5d39/server/bin/code-server --connection-token=remotessh --accept-server-license-terms --start-server --enable-remote-auto-shutdown --socket-path=/tmp/code-bd3d6d38-59de-47a1-8df7-54881cb666dd
                              └─node /home/Dédé/.vscode-server/cli/servers/Stable-e170252f762678dec6ca2cc69aba1570769a5d39/server/out/server-main.js --connection-token=remotessh --accept-server-license-terms --start-server --enable-remote-auto-shutdown --socket-path=/tmp/code-bd3d6d38-59de-47a1-8df7-54881cb666dd
                                  └─node /home/Dédé/.vscode-server/cli/servers/Stable-e170252f762678dec6ca2cc69aba1570769a5d39/server/out/bootstrap-fork --type=ptyHost --logsPath /home/Dédé/.vscode-server/data/logs/20240504T173238
                                      └─zsh -i
                                          └─pstree -alus 271031


Are you sshing to the VM itself or to some management service that gives you console access on the VM somehow? What's the output of pstree -alus "$$"?

I'm using VSCode as you can see in the edit of my question. Were sensible infos shared in my comment? Thank you for helping

I've never used GCP ... what does it look like if you connect using an ordinary ssh client?

I meant GCP as the instance provider. Everything looks normal... Might it be socket related?

List all connected SSH sessions?
summary:
netstat -tnpa | grep 'ESTABLISHED.*sshd'

last | grep "still logged in"

who -a

ss | grep ssh

ps ax | grep sshd

last | head

you can also gleem such information about [past] ssh sessions from /var/log/audit/audit.log provided you have auditd running; however parsing audit.log is easier said than done.
